# WPF application exits immediately after startup in task manager

Tags: .net, wpf, debugging, crash

I have a wpf application running on my computer with visual studio installed.

When I only take the .exe file and copy it to another computer with visual studio it works, but if I copy it to a computer with no visual studio installed, the application starts up in the task manager but closes immediately afterwards with no errors.

Both the computers have .net framworks 4.5 installed.

**EDIT**
The application are using;

```
Microsoft.CSharp
Phidget21.NET
PresentationCore
PresentationFramework
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Xaml
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq
WindowsBase
```

All of the Phidgets drivers and dll's are installed on every computers.

This is the error log:
[image: Error]

Comment: try looking at the EventManager Application logs

Comment: Does the application do any file management or interact with anything that would require admin rights? give it a quick test on the machine that fails by right clicking and run as administrator.

Comment: failing that, I would say that you've used a library that was installed with visual studio but isn't installed with .net, what references are in your project?

Comment: trying to update the phidgets right now..

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the Event Viewer it should give you direction to what crashing the program

[image: Event Viewer]